# Trying to save a copy of a picture selected by FileOpenPicker and saved by FileSavePicker

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

This is the code i have so far that that opens the picture and tries to save it 
any information on why it's not working would be great thanks.

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {



            FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
             PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("jpeg image", new List<string>() 
            { ".jpg" });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "Photo";

            string token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
            StorageFile SaveFile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);

            StorageFile savefile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (SaveFile != null)
            {
                 await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(SaveFile, SaveFile.Name);
            }

        }
```

Comment: *"why it's not working"* - You need to give us more information regarding the problem..for example - Do you see any errors when saving ? or does the application stop responding when you try to save the file ?

Comment: You have two `StorageFile`s with the name `SaveFile` and `saveFile`... which one did you want to save to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the opened file into `FutureAccessList` and then immediately retrieve it as `SaveFile` variable. Right below you create a `saveFile` which I guess is what you wanted to use, but in the `WriteTextAsync` method you pass `SaveFile` as the target, not `saveFile`.

You should definitely improve your naming convention, having two variables differing only in casing is very error prone. Furthermore, local variables should always start with lowercase letter.